# Booting ubuntu from USB error

Tags: boot

Can someone help me? I have these errors when in menu I click on install ubuntu.

```
Disp: error 7 (invalid handle) 00 [] chid 0 mthd 0088 data f0000000
4.399453 nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp: error 5 (invalid state) 00 () chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000
6.063360 sd 6:0:0:0: sdd no caching mode page found
6.063440 sd 6:0:0:0: sdd assuming drive cache: write through
6.399538 nouveau 0000:01:00.0: disp error 5 (invalid state) 00 () chid 0 mthd 0080 data 00000000
```

Comment: @phatez I dont have any os on my computer right now, and I wanted to install the newest version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So a live USB,

Ok, so then try loading back up in your native OS, erasing the USB, erasing any partitions, if you are booting on a mac, using the first add, and then erase it again for good measure, then redo making it a live USB with one of the many programs out there depending on what OS you are on and there is one available for(situationally dependent). Then that should help. If you keep getting the error, try switching the port you are plugging the USB in.

It also may have to do with what version of ubuntu your installing and supported drivers. But, linux is pretty good about working with everything only needing a few tweaks here or there. So unless your doing an old old old.. release, or using an old... "ya you get the idea" .. computer/hardware, then it probably isn't that. more likely reading old data, something got corrupted, or the port doesn't have enough/too much power and is causing an error.

If your updating to 16.04 then there is also some sort of error I remember reading about relating to UEFI boot.

More information would help for a more direct answer from someone with person experience with that exact problem, like type of PC, native OS, Hardware installed, Version of ubuntu you are trying to install, ext. I have seen the

```
6.063360 sd 6:0:0:0: sdd no caching mode page found

6.063440 sd 6:0:0:0: sdd assuming drive cache: write through
```

error just last night when I updated to 16.04 to help answer another question. I erased the USB, several times, and retried, It worked out. I also had the same problem with my USB3 port when I was messing around with different ways to run and manipulate windows 7, Too much power or something, switched ports and it fixed it.

Know I don't have the perfect answer, but I hope it helps some :)